# Socket.io connection keeps dropping when load balancing

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I have been trying for literally months to fix an error being caused when using websockets and load balancing using nginx.

Nginx config:

```
upstream webservers {
  #ip_hash;
  hash $remote_addr;

  server 127.0.0.1:3037;
  server 127.0.0.1:3036;
  server 127.0.0.1:3035;
  server 127.0.0.1:3034;
  server 127.0.0.1:3033;
  server 127.0.0.1:3032;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate PATH-TO-CERT;
  ssl_certificate_key PATH-TO-KEY;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://webservers;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

When using `let socket = io('https://example.com');` in the browser with this config, I get an error message in the browser console on page load:

```
index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=tMQzs11rD9ENKs_7AAAW' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

The connection still works fine, but I assume it has fallen back to long polling.

When using `let socket = io('https://example.com', { transports: ['websocket'] });` I do not get the above message, however get the error message below in regular intervals every few minutes, during which time the websocket connection cuts out for around 5 seconds:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Changing the load balancing mode to `ip_hash` gives a different combination of the same error messages.

I have tried `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3037` - pointing to one of the webservers - which gives no errors, so I'm sure this is an issue with nginx and load balancing.

Server code is standard:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log(`[IO CONNECTION] - ${socket.request.user}`);
});
```